# Should I remove QDebug header for release?

Tags: c++, qt, optimization

I have a Qt Application and I use qDebug message for my application.

However I have gotten lazy and left in a load of:

```
#include <QDebug>
```

in my header files.  Should I remove them for a production deployment and what benefit will it give?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't remove the header inclusion. If you do so, every statement involving qDebug might give a compiler error.

Instead, define the symbol QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT when compiling for release. qDebug will do nothing when that symbol is defined and (hopefully) the compiler will optimize away the calls to a function that does nothing.

Comment: This is not sufficient because you may still get qDebug messages from the Qt libraries. If you are a Windows developer you can check with the dbgview program from SysInternals.

Comment: This is a good option to effectively disable qDebug statements.  However, if you have some minor qDebug statements that are not heavily repeated in loops in code.. you can leave them in release code.  Keep in mind, there is actually a performance hit, when you have many repeated calls to qDebug, as you might in loops.  In such a case, it is important you use the above technique to remove them from release code.

Answer (score 1):

Better idea may be to look into qInstallMsgHandler.  You can redirect your debug messages anywhere you would like.